# When the ultrastrong closure of a *-algebra contains the double commutant

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

As lemma 6 on p.44 of Dixmier's book on Von Neumann algebras, he states that if $A$ is a *-algebra (i.e. possibly without identity, not necessarily closed in any topology) of operators in $B(H)$ such that the closed subspace of $H$ generated by the images of the elements of $A$ is actually all of $H$, then $A'' \subset \bar A$ where the closure is in the ultraweak topology.  I was hoping someone would help me to prove this, because I believe the book's proof is wrong.  What he ends up doing is showing that for every $S \in A''$, $\epsilon>0$ and every $f \in V$ where $V$ is the set of seminorms that generates the ultrastrong topology, there exists $T$ so that $f(T-S)< \epsilon$.  But this is insufficient.  I need there to be an entire net of $T$s that depends only on $f$.  Can someone either give a new argument or explain why the given argument is sufficient?  Thanks.

Comment: Well, the set $V$ of seminorms is directed, right? So there's your net.

Comment: It's indexed by the elements of the countable direct sum of H.  I don't see how these form a net.  Also, I can't say I understand what construction of a net you are suggesting here.  This isn't like sequences, where the analogous fact let's me "choose one for $\epsilon$, then $\epsilon/2$ etc."  EDIT: Those are two separate concerns btw.

Comment: There are many ways to get a net out of this argument. The way I was suggesting is: The set $V$ is partially ordered by $f \leq g$ if $f(T) \leq g(T)$ for all $T$. If $f,g \in V$ then $h(T) = f(T) + g(T)$ is in $V$ and dominates both $f$ and $g$. For each $f \in V$ pick $T_f$ such that $f(T_f - S) \lt 1$. Then $(T_f)_{f \in V}$ is a net converging to $S$ (since $f \in V$ implies $f/\varepsilon \in V$), so it suffices to show that for every $f$ and every $\varepsilon$ you can find $T$ such that $f(T - S) \lt \varepsilon$ which seems to be what Dixmier is doing.

Comment: So yes, in a way this is exactly like sequences... See also [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=a1R0livwR9AC&pg=PA63).

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question.